# How do I a line to dreamweaver that I drew on Geojson.io?

Tags: line, dreamweaver, geojson

The code below is what I am using. Basically modified from the polygons I was drawing, but the lines arent showing up...

```
// Construct the Venue Line.
theVenue = new google.maps.LineString({
  paths: outlineCoords,
  strokeColor: '#ffba20',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#ffba20',
  fillOpacity: 1
});

// ...

theVenue.setMap(map);

// outline the venue
var theVenue;

// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
var outlineCoords = [new google.maps.LatLng(39.9066747476479, -75.2781808376312),
new google.maps.LatLng(39.9083124955562, -75.2793931961059),
new google.maps.LatLng(39.910123025565, -75.2808094024658),
```

Comment: Hi Franz. It looks like your code snipping is incomplete (outlineCoords is never finished or used). Is there more you can add?  Also: what is your goal here?

Comment: Hey David, sorry for the lack of context. I used Geojson to trace lines on a map and I am using Dreamweaver to customize the map. I am good with the polygons but for some reason I cannot get the lines... here is what I have...